# Firefox build gives "[Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost"

Tags: firefox, browser, crash, gdb

I built Firefox 57.0 using source code from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/57.0/source/).

After building it successfully, I ran `./firefox-57.0/objdir-ff-dbg/dist/bin/firefox --no-remote --headless file:///home/ug16zy2/test.html`, it gives:

`###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost`

and I don't think `test.html` is loaded successfully.

It seems Firefox crashed on start up (maybe)? Do you know what happened and why, or how to debug it? Thanks in advance.

PS: I build Firefox with options:

```
ac_add_options --disable-jemalloc
ac_add_options --enable-crashreporter
ac_add_options --disable-elf-hack
export MOZ_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=1
ac_add_options --enable-debug-symbols
ac_add_options --disable-install-strip
ac_add_options --disable-strip
ac_add_options --enable-optimize="-g -O2"
ac_add_options --enable-debug
ac_add_options --enable-valgrind
ac_add_options --disable-profiling
ac_add_options --disable-tests
ac_add_options --enable-gczeal
JS_GC_ZEAL=IncrementalMultipleSlices
```

PS: I have to make Firefox 57.0 work because I am playing with a vulnerability on that version. I'm running it on a server without display, so have to use "--headless".

Comment: I see these errors when Firefox causes GNOME to lock, with the log prefix 'gnome-shell[2702]'. Happens at least once per day, requiring a hard reset. Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with Firefox 83.0.